# How to Authenticate mysql Encode() password from laravel code

Tags: laravel

hi I am new in laravel and facing mysql function matching problem with laravel.
I have a table named users where column userid and password to be matched to logged in from application. The users.password field value is encode(value,'1234') by default in mysql.
Now how can I authenticate in laravel code.here I think DB::raw() can not be use.
how can I manage to match user input password with  mysql encode() password in laravel code?

the laravel code is

```
$name = $request->input('uid');
$pass = $request->input('password');
        if (Auth::attempt(['userid' => $name, 'password' => $pass])) {
          //send to protected page of application
            return redirect()->intended('checkout');
        } 
        else {
            //redirect to login page
        }
```

Comment: Laravel has password encryption by default. But if you want to use a custom way of encoding passwords, you will have to create a [`UserProvider`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Contracts/Auth/UserProvider.php) for this.

Comment: Actually I have to transform the user input password to mysql encode() value to match with table value

Comment: This person wrote some PHP classes to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20482004/php-implementation-of-mysql-encode-decode-functions